# how to append string to the primary key in django model

Tags: python, django

I want to differentiate between some local data from remote data ..So i want to make primary key of local data to be something like: local_1,local_2...etc.

My model is:

```
class coupon(models.Model):

    success = models.IntegerField()                      # Count of the number of times people have made it work
    failure = models.IntegerField()                      # Count of the number of times this has failed    
    couponDescription = models.TextField()               # Coupon Description
    active =  models.BooleanField(default=True)
    couponCode = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    couponStore = models.CharField(max_length=30)        # Store Name
    featured =  models.BooleanField(default=False)
    couponTitle = models.CharField(max_length=100)       # Coupon Title
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    lastTested = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)     # When was the coupon last tested
    localCouponId = models.CharField(max_length=30,primary_key=True)
```

so how do i make `localCouponId` auto increment with string `local_` concatenated with integers like...1,2,3,4....etc.

Comment: I think you should extend `Coupon` and create `LocalCoupon` and `RemoteCoupon` instead. Or add a boolean like `is_remote`.

Comment: actually coupon 'id' can clash between local and remote data...i want different coupon 'id' in order to load the comment from the Db or submit them...also user can submit coupons and i am storing those coupon on the local DB means in the app DB itself not on the Api DB.....